# resource busy while rebuilding an index

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, indexing, locking

There is a table `T` with column `a`:

```
CREATE TABLE T {
  id_t integer not null,
  text varchar2(100),
  a integer
} 
/

ALTER TABLE T ADD CONSTRAINT PK_T PRIMARY KEY (ID_T)
/
```

Index was created like this:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_T$A ON T(a);
```

Also there's such a check constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE T ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK (a is null or a = 1);
```

Most of the records in `T` have null value of `a`, so the query using the index works really fast if the index is in consistent state and statistics for it is up to date.

But the problem is that values of `a` of some rows change really frequently (some rows get null value, some get 1), and I need to rebuild the index let's say every hour.

However, really often when the job doing this, trying to rebuild the index, it gets an exception:

```
ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified
```

Can anybody help me with coping with this issue?

Comment: You could handle it with a retry mechanism. Catching the resource busy exception and try again until it succeeds.

Comment: What effect is the rapid change having on your index that drives the need for these frequent rebuilds?

Comment: Statistics on it expires really fast. Rebuiling regathers statistics and makes the index smaller (read a query on it becomes faster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index rebuild is not needed in most cases. Of course newly created indexes are efficient and their efficiency decreases over time. But this process stops after some time - it simply converges to some level.

If you really need to optimize indexes try to use less invasive DDL command "ALTER INDEX SHRINK SPACE COMPACT".

PS: I would also recommend you to use some smaller block size (4K or 8K) for you tablespace storage.

Comment: Imagine a situation when in the table there're millions of rows and only one hundred of them have not null value of indexed column, an hour later not null values have absolutely different rows (previous ones got nulls in it), are you sure that index won't continue permanently growing and getting less and less efficient?

Comment: Oracle indexes are self-defragmenting. At least at some level. It also depend on order of column indexed. If an index does not suit your searching needs look for "star design schema" - which is used in datawarehousing systems. It's quite simple. Or there is also an option to "COMPRESS" the index.

Comment: One more comment, index "size" can be expressed using different metrics. segment size - how many bytes index occupies. Number of leaf blocks - how many leaf blocks index has. Each of them can it's own meaning. (btw: Index consists of branch blocks, leaf blocks and free blocks)

Comment: [In another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643772/what-are-the-differences-between-shrink-space-compact-and-coalesce) I'm asking about differences between `shrink space compact` and `coalesce`, because there's no enough information about it in the docs. Found that Tom tested both commands and found that shrinking still locking the table. So, what the differences then with `rebuild` remain if we don't talk about physical placement of the index? You can add your opinion there if you like.

Comment: You are right, coleasce is even better option for you. The REBUILD usually has to allocate some space in TEMP tablespace(which requires additional disk IO) and also has to sort records in a table. While SHRINK and COALESCE go through tree's leaf pages and optimize their space usage. Both reduce number of leaf blocks, SHRINK also reduces index segment size.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding "ONLINE" to that index rebuild statement?

Edit: If online rebuild is not available then you might look at a fast refresh on commit materialised view to store the rowid's or primary keys of rows that have a 1 for column A.

Start with a look at the documentation:-

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28326/repmview.htm
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6002.htm#SQLRF01302

You'd create a materialised view log on the table, and then a materialised view.

Think in particular about the resource requirements for this: changes to the master table require a change vector to be written to the materialised view log, which is effectively an additional insert for every change. Then the changes have to be propagated to another table (the materialised view storage table) with additional queries. It is by no means a low-impact option.

Comment: Rebuild online is enterprise option that is not available for me.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you mean with materealized views? It looks really nice.

Answer (score 1):

**Rebuilding for Performance**

Most Oracle experts are skeptical of frequently rebuilding indexes.  For example, a quick glance at the presentation [Rebuilding the Truth](http://richardfoote.files.wordpress.com/2007/12/index-internals-rebuilding-the-truth.pdf) will show you that indexes do not behave in the naive way many people assume they do.

One of the relevant points in that presentation is "fully deleted blocks are recycled and are not generally problematic".  If your values completely change, then your index should not grow infinitely large.  Although your indexes are used in a non-typical way, that
behavior is probably a good thing.

Here's a quick example.  Create 1 million rows and index 100 of them.

```
--Create table, constraints, and index.
CREATE TABLE T
(
    id_t integer primary key,
    text varchar2(100),
    a integer check (a is null or a = 1)
);

CREATE INDEX IDX_T$A ON T(a);

--Insert 1M rows, with 100 "1"s.
insert into t
select level, level, case when mod(level, 10000) = 0 then 1 else null end
from dual connect by level <= 1000000;
commit;

--Initial sizes:
select segment_name, bytes/1024/1024 MB
from dba_segments
where segment_name in ('T', 'IDX_T$A');

SEGMENT_NAME    MB
T               19
IDX_T$A         0.0625
```

Now completely shuffle the index rows around 1000 times.

```
--Move the 1s around 1000 times.  Takes about 6 minutes.
begin
    for i in 9000 .. 10000 loop
        update t
        set a = case when mod(id_t, i) = 0 then 1 else null end
        --Don't update if the vlaue is the same
        where nvl(a,-1) <> nvl(case when mod(id_t,i) = 0 then 1 else null end,-1);
        commit;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

The index segment size is still the same.

```
--The the index size is the same.
select segment_name, bytes/1024/1024 MB
from dba_segments
where segment_name in ('T', 'IDX_T$A');

SEGMENT_NAME    MB
T               19
IDX_T$A         0.0625
```

**Rebuilding for Statistics**

It's good to worry about the statistics of objects whose data changes so dramatically.  But again, although your system is unusual, it may work fine with the default Oracle behavior.  Although the rows indexed may completely change, the relevant statistics may stay the same.  If there are always 100 rows indexed, the number of rows, blocks, and distinctness will stay the same.

Perhaps the clustering factor will significantly change, if the 100 rows shift from being completely random to being very close to each other.  But even that may not matter.  If there are millions of rows, but only 100 indexed, the optimizer's decision will probably be the same regardless of the clustering factor.  Reading 1 block (awesome clustering factor) or reading 100 blocks (worst-case clustering factor) will still look much better than doing a full table scan of millions of rows.

But statistics are complicated, I'm surely over-simplifying things.  If you need to keep your statistics a specific way, you may want to lock them.  Unfortunately you can't lock just an index, but you can lock the table and it's dependent indexes.

```
begin
    dbms_stats.lock_table_stats(ownname => user, tabname => 'T');
end;
/
```

**Rebuilding anyway**

If a rebuild is still necessary, @Robe Eleckers idea to retry should work.  Although instead of an exception, it would be easier to set [DDL_LOCK_TIMEOUT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/initparams074.htm#I1010267).

```
alter session set ddl_lock_timeout = 500;
```

The session will still need to get an exclusive lock on the table, but this will make it much easier to find the right window of opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

Since the field in question has very low cardinality I would suggest using a bitmap index and skipping the rebuilds altogether.

```
CREATE BITMAP INDEX IDX_T$A ON T(a);
```

Note (as mentioned in comments): transactional performance is very low for bitmap indexes so this would only work well if there are very few overlapping transactions doing updates to the table.

Comment: That's going to be rather bad for concurrency if the values are fast changing from multiple sessions, though.

Comment: It's [absolutely not recommended](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sharma-indexes-093638.html) to use a bitmap index if data changes simultaneously by several processes and very frequently.

Comment: And by the way `select * from v$option where parameter = 'Bit-mapped indexes'` says that it's not available in standart edition as well..